zsh: command not found for a python package
I installed a package dicedb-cli on my mac:
$ pip3 install dicedb-cli

I can see it at location:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages

But when I try to run command, I get:
zsh: command not found: dice

How to add it to path?
Edit: So I added full path(export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dice") to ~./zshrc. But I still see same issue.

Check that the directories listed in your $PATH contain the executable file dice (not the python package), edit it accordingly if the directory containing it is missing and run the rehash command after the installation if you don't open a new shell session.

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/dice

Is not a place where pip put the executable, it should be in some bin file, I guess bin file in site-packages.
Try one of pip3 show dicedb-cli or
find /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/ -name "dice"

and see which bin it located in. Might also be in usr/local/bin or $HOME/.local/bin/.
Add the whole bin to path —
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/bin"

Then source ~/.zshrc and you might need to close and reopen the terminal.

I've found Mac can be pretty tricky with python libraries
you need to find the dicedb executable file, most likely within:
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages

You need to add the path within the configuration file which would be:
Bash: .bashrc or .bash_profile
Zsh: .zshrc

then add the following in the file (replace with dicedb path)
export PATH="/path/to/dice:$PATH"


It should rather be /path/to/directory_containing_dice though (the current wording is ambigious imho).
